# Having trouble with using sympy subs command when trying to solve a function at an x value of 0

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

I have a function [ -4*x/sqrt(1 - (1 - 2*x^2)^2) + 2/sqrt(1 - x^2) ] that I need to evaluate at x=0. However, whenever you graph this function, for some interval of y there are many y-values at x=0. This leads me to think that the (subs) command can only return one y-value. Any help or elaboration on this? Thank you!

Here's my code if it might help:

```
x = symbols('x')    
f = 2*asin(x)        # f(x) function
g = acos(1-2*x**2)   # g(x) function
eq = diff(f-g)       # evaluating the derivative of f(x) - g(x)
eq.subs(x, 0)        # substituting 0 for x in the derivative of f(x) - g(x)
```

After I run the code, it returns NaN, which I assume is because substituting in 0 for x returns not a *single* number, but a range of numbers.

[Here is the graph of the function to be evaluated at x=0:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMclc.png)

Comment: You probably need https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html#limits

Comment: `limit(eq, x, 0, '-')` gives 4.  `limit(eq, x, 0, '+')` seems to run forever ...

Comment: `diff(g).subs(x, e)` approaches `+/- 2` as `e` approaches `0` from either side.

Comment: wolfram alpha gives 0 as the limit on the right and 4 as the limit on the left.  SymPy seems to be very confused.

Comment: If a substitution results in `0/0` in the expression, nan will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should always give SymPy as many assumptions as possible. For example, it can't pull an `x**2` out of a `sqrt` because it thinks `x` is complex.

A factorization an then a simplification solves the problem. SymPy can't do L'Hopital on `eq = A + B` since it does not know that both A and B converge.  So you have to guide it a little by bringing the fractions together and then simplifying:

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x', real=True)
f = 2*asin(x)        # f(x) function
g = acos(1-2*x**2)   # g(x) function
eq = diff(f-g)       # evaluating the derivative of f(x) - g(x)
eq = simplify(factor(eq))
print(eq)

print(limit(eq, x, 0, "+"))
print(limit(eq, x, 0, "-"))
```

Outputs:

```py
(-2*x + 2*Abs(x))/(sqrt(1 - x**2)*Abs(x))
0
4
```

`simplify`, `factor` and  `expand` do wonders.